# Create new folder with pathlib and write files into it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I'm doing something like this:

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path("temp/").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

with p.open("temp."+fn, "w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

> Error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open'

Obviously, based on the error message, `mkdir` returns `None`.

Jean-Francois Fabre suggested this correction:

```
p = pathlib.Path("temp/")
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

with p.open("temp."+fn, "w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    ...
```

This triggered a new error message:

> File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1164, in open
>       opener=self._opener)
>   TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: that's because `mkdir` returns `None`. You cannot chain calls like that.

Comment: did you try `p = pathlib.Path("temp/"); p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` then the usual `filepath = p / fn;
with filepath.open("w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(result)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module offers an `open` method that has a slightly different signature to the built-in [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

**pathlib:**

```
Path.open(mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)
```

**The built-in:**

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

In the case of this `p = pathlib.Path("temp/")` it has created a path `p` so calling `p.open("temp."+fn, "w", encoding ="utf-8")` with positional arguments (not using keywords) expects the first to be `mode`, then `buffering`, and `buffering` expects an integer, and that is the essence of the error; an integer is expected but it received the string `'w'`.

This call `p.open("temp."+fn, "w", encoding ="utf-8")` is trying to open the path `p` (which is a directory) and also providing a filename which isn't supported. You have to construct the full path, and then either call the path's open method or pass the full path into the open built-in function.

Comment: isn't this simpler: `p = pathlib.Path("temp/"); p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`?

Comment: @CharlieParker The OP's question can be summarised as "I tried this and had an error ... I tried that and had another error"  Read the code examples in the question carefully and you see that the errors relate to (very common) confusion between the `method` signature and the built-in `function` signature. It's useful to imagine trying to explain the issue to yourself, back when you were first learning, in a way that you wish someone would have helped you then.

Comment: @CharlieParker (3 years ago now) I didn't suggest code or any opinion about what might be simpler, so I am not sure what you are asking, Also not sure why I got a downvote without a reason or feedback.

Answer (score 150):

You could try:

```
p = pathlib.Path("temp/")
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
fn = "test.txt" # I don't know what is your fn
filepath = p / fn
with filepath.open("w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

You shouldn't give a string as path. It is your object `filepath` which has the method `open`.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open)

Answer (score 51):

You can directly initialize `filepath` and create parent directories for `parent` attribute:

```
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path("temp/test.txt")
filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

with filepath.open("w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 22):

Maybe, this is the shortest code you want to do.

```py
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path("temp/")
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
(p / ("temp." + fn)).write_text(result, encoding="utf-8")
```

In most cases, it doesn't need even open() context by using [write_text()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text) instead.

Comment: Path.write_text() only writes a string. If we have a list of strings, it won't work.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do something like:

```
text_path = Path("random/results").resolve()
text_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
(text_path / f"{title}.txt").write_text(raw_text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. The full `pathlib` version would be something like:

```py
folder = "path/to/folder"
file_base = "file_name_base"
file_extension = ".extension"

p_folder = pathlib.Path(folder)
p_file_base = p_folder / file_base
p_file = p_file_base.with_suffix(file_extension)

p_file.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # or `p_folder`

p_file.write_text("Your text here", encoding ="utf-8")
```

I decomposed all steps to make it as transparent as possible, you can shorten this code.
For example:

```py
p_file = pathlib.Path("path/to/folder/file_base")
p_file.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
p_file.with_suffix(".extension").write_text("Your text here", encoding ="utf-8")
```