# How do I use \ in a string?

Tags: python, special-characters

I am trying to create a directory in my Python code but I can't use backslash `\` in a string. Every time I do it gives me an unexpected token error.

I would like my code to look something like this:

```
dir = os.getcwd() + "\FolderIWantToCreate"
```

If I use `/` (forward slash), it gives me an error because my directory paths use backslash. However if I type `\` (backslash) anywhere in my code, even inside `""`, it doesn't register the backslash as a string, it says unexpected token.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Use raw string --> `r"\FolderIWantToCreate"` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use backslash in file name ??

Comment: @MD5 I think he means path separator... welcome to the Windows world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can either escape the [escape character](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) `\` by adding an extra `\` before it, like this: `"\\FolderIWantToCreate"`,
2. You can use the `r` prefix before the string to tell python that the string that follows is a [raw string](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string), like this: `r"\FolderIWantToCreate"`

Answer (score 6):

\ is the escape character in python. If you want to use \ in a string you have to escape it, i.e.:

```
"\\"
```

For more, see: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with paths and look e.g. for OS intercompatibility, consider using the `pathlib` package. More info on how to use it when e.g. creating new folders, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518669/create-new-folder-in-python-with-pathlib-and-write-files-into-it).

If you really have to use that notation anyways, then an option would be to make it a "raw" string:

```py
s = r'\FolderIWantToCreate'
```

more on that e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Escape sequence when ever you are using special characters

```
dir = os.getcwd() + "\\FolderIWantToCreate"
```

Reference : [2.4.1 String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

`dir = os.getcwd() + "\\FolderIWantToCreate"`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another answer which I think you should know;

Assuming you are on Windows

You can use `os.path.join()` with `os.sep` to overcome the issue you are facing.

I do not have a Windows VM with me to give you a concrete example.

Comment: You don't need `os.sep`; `os.path.join` already uses it implicitly; `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "FolderIWantToCreate")` does the job.