# How to create Folder on the basis of files in a specific folder

Tags: python, pandas, text, directory, mkdir

I have a folder which comprises of several pdfs and word files.I want to create a new folder where I want subfolders on the basis of the files which I read earlier and each sub folder should have 3 blank text files lets say test1.txt,test2.txt,test.txt
I am new to python kindly help....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518669/create-new-folder-in-python-with-pathlib-and-write-files-into-it

Comment: @ruslankrivoshein The above link you shared doesnt work.If there is any other way kindly let me know.I need to read a folder in which there are pdf and doc files present.On the basis of those file name i have to folders and in each folder random 3 text file should be present....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

files = Path().iterdir()

for file in files:
    new_file_path = Path(f'./{file.stem}')
    new_file_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    for i in range(3):
        p = new_file_path / f'{i + 1}.txt'
        with p.open('w') as nf:
             nf.write('')
```

I run this script within directory, where I have `one.doc`, `two.doc` and `three.pdf`, for instance. After that I get next:

```
one/
    1.txt
    2.txt
    3.txt
two/
    1.txt
    2.txt
    3.txt
three/
    1.txt
    2.txt
    3.txt
one.doc
two.doc
three.pdf
```

I hope, you are able to remove then unused files.