# How to create a directory?

Tags: python, directory

I tried using open but it gives an error that the folder doesn't exist, which makes no sense since this is a command to create a folder, not read one. I saw [Automatically creating directories with file output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output#comment102334164_12517490), but there is an error saying this is a `Errno 30: Read only system: "/folder"`. Does anyone know how to avoid Error 30?

My code so far:

```
import os
filename = "/folder/y.txt"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("FOOBAR")
```

Comment: You don't have write access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create new folder in python with pathlib and write files into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518669/create-new-folder-in-python-with-pathlib-and-write-files-into-it)

Comment: @sehan2: That's not the same problem — so, no, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I get the similar problem but code works when I use `"/home/furas/y.txt"` Problem can be that you create folder in main folder `/` and it may have special setting in system for security reason - and maybe this folder already existed before you you use `makedirs` - and because you use `exist_ok=True` so it would run it without error when folder already exist. Better create folders in your home folder.

Comment: I get the similar problem but code works when I use `"/home/furas/y.txt"` Problem can be that you create folder in main folder `/` and it may have special setting in system for security reason. And maybe this folder already existed (with read only settings)  before you used `makedirs` - and because you use `exist_ok=True` so it would run without error message so it could look like it created this folder. Better create folders in your home folder.

Comment: Use `filename = "folder/y.txt"`. The leading `/` in your code tries to make a folder at the root of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured i just shouldn't put the slash behind the "folder"`filename = "folder/y.txt" os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True) with open(filename, "w") as f: f.write("FOOBAR")`