# Using column value as output path location python

Tags: python

Is it possible if i have several columns to have my output go to. If I want to use column 3 as the storage location of my output files. main_folder below contains folder1,folder2, folder3

```
C:/Desktop/main_folder/
file.txt

Bob   November  folder_1
Jon   January   folder_3
Sam   December  folder_1
Jane  April     folder_2
```

```
path = /Desktop/main_folder/*
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input:
    for lines in input:
        line = line.strip()
        with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(line, path)
```

Is it possible to select just column 3 and use that path as output?

Comment: Does your script run? `path = /Desktop/main_folder/*` seems incorrect syntax, and `outfile.write(line, path)` does not need a path. But `output` as path for the output-file needs to be build from `path` and the third column.

Comment: correct. `with open(f'{line}/{output}', 'w') as outfile:`.
I think you also need to handle if the storage path is not created yet check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651935/9816541

Comment: @Amzar You mean `line.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        columns = line.strip().split()  # split line into columns using spaces as delimiter
        path = os.path.join('/Desktop/main_folder', columns[2])  # path is built from main-folder and third column
        with open(path, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(line)  # write the line to it's respective file path
```

#### Step by step explanation

1. This code reads each line of the input file
2. Then splits it into columns using the `split()` method.
3. It takes the third column (index 2) and combines it with the base path `/Desktop/main_folder` using `os.path.join()` to create the full output path.
4. Finally, it opens the output file at the specified path and writes the original line to it.

Note: this code assumes that the input file is in the format you provided, with the columns separated by spaces. If the columns are separated by a different character, you will need to use a different method to split the line into columns.

See also: [python 3.x - Create new folder with pathlib and write files into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518669/create-new-folder-with-pathlib-and-write-files-into-it/47651935#47651935)

Comment: need to define the filename in `path`

Comment: Please avoid using `input` as a variable name as it has a special use in Python.

Comment: I fixed your indentation along with improvements (see edits). You could add links to Python docs for the methods you mentioned. This might help to introduce their usage.